# Is there a way to view all Spaces in macOS (using a shortcut)

Tags: macos, shortcut, spaces, mission-control

I'm looking for a way to view all desktops (Spaces) at once with a single shortcut (like <kbd>Command</kbd>  <kbd>↑</kbd>   for Mission Control). If I could archive the same effect you get when you use Mission Control and go up with your mouse as explained in: Apple Support Document [Work in Multiple Spaces](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/work-in-multiple-spaces-mh14112/11.0/mac/11.0)

I noticed that when you have at least one fullscreen app open (and it is focused), Mission Control will always show the Spaces preview but in all other circumstances it will only list other spaces in at the top as *Desktop 1*, *Desktop 2*, *Desktop 3* etc.

This is the effect I want to achieve (when activating Mission Control; show a preview of the Spaces)

[image: Example of Mission control being active while showing other spaces]

Any 3rd party options would also be acceptable.

Comment: "...it will only list other spaces in at the top as Desktop 1, Desktop 2, Desktop 3 etc." I'm only on 10.14, but when I mouse up to the line that shows "Desktop 1" etc., it automatically expands into miniature screen images. Not a one-step procedure, but it does get what you want.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get around this. Why? I use a lot of keyboard shortcuts to manage applications and my desktop. I just would like to see with 1 keystroke or movement what is open on all desktops.

Comment: I do not quite get your question. Is it the three fingers up swipe (swipe up with 3 fingers on the trackpad)? Could you please clarify.

Comment: @Thinkr, yes. What I would like to achieve is the view as pictured in the example (Mission Control with the preview of the different desktops) but without doing a 3 finger swipe up and moving the mouse to the top of the screen. I would like this to be triggerd by a shortcut on my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

[Totalspaces](https://totalspaces.binaryage.com/) does this. Currently it's available for intel macs, and requires users to disable System Integrity Protection to run on macOS 10.11 or higher.

Comment: This looks great! I'll give it a try.

Comment: I see that they describe "System Integrity Protection" as a systems tweak but I don't agree. I understand that it can't work with SIP enabled but calling it a tweak (as they do" is an understatement.

Comment: I’m sure they’d appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

BetterTouchTool has an option for this. Go to keyboard shortcuts and add a new action. Search for "Mission Control" and you will see there are 2 options: 1. "Mission Control" and 2. "Mission Control & Immediately Show Desktop Preview"